# How delegate invoke parent library event from referenced class

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, invoke

I write a code in c sharp in which I have made two class library,**MathOperation** and **CalculationManager**.

MathOperation have **reference** of CalculationManager. Now what I want to do is that I want to invoke MathOperation class method from the CalculationManager class.

May be delegate help me to solve this issue but problem is syntax,need some syntax or example. [This](http://akashsoni7.blogspot.com/2012/12/c-sending-information-data-from-child.html) show me how to use delegate on same class library need help on how delegate used in different libraries.

```
 class Programe
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Creating a parent class
                CalculationManager p = new CalculationManager();
                p.Add();

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// this method call from child
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="message"> child delegate deliver this parameter</param>
            public void AddImpact(string message)
            {

            }
        }
```

**Note:** CalculationManager class does not has reference to MathOperation.

Comment: "**MathOperation** have reference of **CalculationManager**. Now what I want to do is that I want to invoke **MathOperation** class method from the **CalculationManager** class." - Does the other way round happen? Does **CalculationManager** class has reference to **MathOperation**?

Comment: Could you past a sample of code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an event in `CalculationManager` that the `MathOperator` hooks. Here's a very simplified example of how it could go. There's no difference how delegates work, whether they are defined and used in same or different libraries.

```
namespace ManagerLibrary
{
    public delegate int Operation(int x, int y);

    public class CalculationManager
    {
        public event Operation OperationNeeded;

        public int? Operate(int x, int y)
        {
            return (Operate != null)
                ? Operate(x, y)
                : (int?)null;
        }
    }
}

//In some other library
using ManagerLibrary;

namespace OperationLibrary
{
    public class MathOperation
    {
        public CalculationManager Manager { get; set; }

        public MathOperation(CalculationManager manager)
        {
            Manager = manager;
            Manager.OperationNeeded += Manager_OperationNeeded;
        }

        int Manager_OperationNeeded(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}

//Usage (maybe in a third library)
var manager = new CalculationManager();
var operation = new MathOperation(manager);

var result = manager.Operate(2, 3);
```